# Post Method - Changing a Nested Value

Tags: rest, tfs

I am trying to change a value - specifically a variable - of one of my TFS 2017 builds. To my understanding, Patch is not supported at all. I can successfully queue a build with the Post method and I am trying to use the same command change a value as well.

When I run the Get method, I have:

```
*A bunch of text*
"variables": {
    "system.debug": {
        "value": "false",
        "allowOverride": true
    },
     "BuildVersion": {
        "value": "ValueIWantToChange"
    }
},
*A bunch of text*
```

I need to change the Build Version and everything else will stay the same.  My body in Postman looks like:

```
{
    "Variables":
    {
        "BuildVersion": 
        {
            "value": NewValue
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this in Postman, I get this error:

> "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: definition.Repository"

Could anyone tell me where I am going wrong or if this is possible using another method?

Comment: is `variables` nested under something?

Comment: no, I guess I should change the format a little

Comment: I meant the original one, not your replacement

Comment: nope it's the same

Comment: Can you take the get method's output, replace the value, and post back the full object?

Comment: What API version are you using?

Comment: I'm using API ver. 3.0

Comment: @SomewhatStudent Do you mean that you want to update the value of the variable in build definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem awhile back and forgot to update. My initial task was to get the API for octopus so this is the long version. If youre only interested in the REST commands, refer to the last section of code. Just wanted to add the rest in for extra context.

```
#Create a folder
if(test-Path C:\Test){}
else{
new-item -path "C:\" -name "Test" -ItemType "directory"}

$encodedPAT = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$TFSAPIKeyForAutomatedBuild"))
$GetURI = "$MyURI"

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $encodedPAT")
[string]$Global:ChangeVersion = [version]$OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action[Deploy Package].Package.NuGetPackageVersion"]
write-host $ChangeVersion
$GetBuildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -header $headers -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $GetUri
write-host $GetBuildResponse
$y = convertTo-json $GetBuildresponse -depth 99 | Out-file -FilePath "C:\test\FromPostmanCopy.json"


$z = (get-content "C:\test\FromPostmanCopy.json") | select-string -pattern '(?<=value":  "2.)(.*)(?=")' | % { $_.Matches} | % { $_.value }
Write-Host $z
$Content = (Get-Content "C:\Test\FromPostmanCopy.json")
$content -replace "2.$z", $changeVersion | out-file "C:\Test\FromPostmanCopy.json"
$Content = (Get-Content "C:\Test\FromPostmanCopy.json")
$Buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $GetURI -Method Put -header $headers -Body $content -ContentType application/json
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you want to update the build definition base on you description.

To update the build definition with the REST API you need to use **PUT** method, please see [Definitions - Update Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/update%20definition?view=vsts-rest-4.1) for details.

1. Get the build definition first:

   ```
   GET http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ScrumProject/_apis/build/definitions/6?api-version=3.2
   ```
2. Copy **all the json response** from the first step as the request body,
   then change the value of the specific variable which you want to be
   modified.

   ```
   PUT http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ScrumProject/_apis/build/definitions/6?api-version=3.2

   Content-Type: application/json
   ```

**Note** that you need to provide the **latest revision** in request body:

---

**UPDATE:**

You can also use PowerShell by calling the REST API to update the specific variable value, just try below sample: (*the variable name is `lctest` in below sample, you just need to replace it with your own variable name.*)

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$definitionid = "6",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#Get build definition
$defurl = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/build/definitions/$($definitionid)?api-version=3.2"            
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $defurl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

#Set new value for the specific variable
$definition.variables.lctest.value = "1.0.0.4"

$json = @($definition) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

#Update the definition
$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $defurl  -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

write-host $definition.variables.lctest.value
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah this is along the lines of what I was trying to do. By copying the response, do you mean just put it in to a file to then read and change my value? I thought there might have been a better solution than going through all of that.

Comment: @SomewhatStudent Not put it into a file, just put the build definition json response as the request body with PUT method, then change the value which you wanted to be modified, and **you have to copy all of the json response**, otherwise you will miss other settings once you sent the request.

Comment: @SomewhatStudent Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you change a value within the response without sending it to a file and change it then. I obviously cannot send back the same response that I receive. Currently I have the request sent into a file and I can change the value pretty easy. I am now running into an error "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'. and for reference, this is my call: 
$Buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -header $headers -ContentType application/json -Uri $PostUri -Body $content (Where content is my updated json file)

Comment: @SomewhatStudent Well, you mean using the PowerShell to update the build definition by calling the REST API. Yeah, that should be a good solution to update the specific value of a variable. Please see the updated answer and code sample.